# How to map props to object value React Big Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm using the [Big Calendar React component](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html) and it takes an array of objects, **EVENTS**, with **start** and **end** for keys and dates for values.

```
// event state
 events: [
    {
      start: new Date(moment('2018-08-11T02:26:00+00:00')),
      end: new Date(moment('2018-08-11T02:26:00+00:00'))
    },
   //... rest of objects
  ]
```

I'm using redux to bring in my own array of events objects but with a different key name of **dateGoingLIVE**.

I want to create a new array of my array of objects, **myEvents**, with the key start and end but with the value of my props dateGoingLive.

```
const { myEvents } = this.props.myEvents;

const newEvents: [
    {
      start: myEvents.dateGoingLive,
      end: myEvents.dateGoingLive
    },
   //... rest of objects
  ]
```

The reason START and END share the same dateGoingLive prop is because it's a single day event.

BTW both arrays of objects have properties like creator, name, etc, but didn't think it was important to paste in here. If it is otherwise please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to take your array of objects with a `dateGoingLive` key to an array of objects with `start` and `end` keys.

```
const { myEvents } = this.props;
const newEvents = myEvents.map(event => ({
  start: event.dateGoingLive,
  end: event.dateGoingLive
}));
```

Comment: that was it, so I see how you created a new event and actually mapped it from there instead of pushing or anything like that which was what I was trying to do. thxs